# Error trying to Input a BehaviorSubject into a library component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-library

I created a library for my components and that components have an Input that contain data and settings to the component.
That object is inside a BehaviorSubject so I can change the data from anywhere and subscribe it to detect changes.
The library is separated from the project so it have its own node modules.
I create the BehaviorSubject in the Father (Project component) and input the variable into the Child(Library component).
The problem is that I cant Input the variable because the import of the BehaviorSubject is diferent in the components.

Error:

```
Type 'import("C:......../Libraries/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/BehaviorSubject").BehaviorSubject<import("C:/......../Libraries/projects/lib/src/lib/table/table").TableDatasource>' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/......../Libraries/projects/lib/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/BehaviorSubject").BehaviorSubject<import("C:/......../Libraries/projects/lib/src/lib/table/table").TableDatasource>'.
```

I have been trying to export the rxjs from the library in the public api and use that but didnt work. What I expect is that I can use the sabe rxjs in the library and the project so I can share data between them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you passing the BehaviorSubject as opposed to simply subscribing to it and sending the data with the `async` pipe?

Comment: I am using the behaviorSubject because the object I am passing is complex and I need to subscribe in the father and the child component